# StoryBook for Vue: [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, storybook

I want to build my frontend using [Gridsome](https://gridsome.org/) and [StoryBook](https://storybook.js.org/) to offer our developers and product-managers a web-based component-library.

Gridsome is working as it should. Running StoryBook via `npm run storybook` works. But when I visit the page in Chrome there is console-error saying: *[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.*

I've followed the StoryBook documentation to setup my settings. But I've created a customized webpack.config.js because I have global (scss) resources which should be loaded and injected in all my components (such as global variables).

I think the problem is somewhere in my webpack-file. But changing things results in more errors^^

My Component:

```
<template>
    <h1 :style="styles">
        <slot></slot>
    </h1>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: "FaaH1",
        props: {
            color: {
                type: String,
                required: false
            }
        },
        computed: {
            styles(){
                return {
                    color: this.color
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<style scoped lang="scss">
    h1 {
        font-size:   $font-size-base * 2.5;
        color: $secondary;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: $font-weight-extrabold;
    }
</style>
```

My StoryBook Story:

```
import { linkTo } from "@storybook/addon-links";
import Vue from 'vue';

import FaaH1 from "../src/components/texts/headings/FaaH1";

export default {
    title: 'Headings',
};

export const faaH1 = () => ({
    components: {FaaH1},
    template: '<faa-h1>Heading H1</faa-h1>'
});
```

My config.js:

```
import { configure } from '@storybook/vue';

// Components-Import
import FaaH1 from "../src/components/texts/headings/FaaH1";

import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.component('faa-h1', FaaH1);

// automatically import all files ending in *.stories.js
configure(require.context('../stories', true, /\.stories\.js$/), module);
```

And finally my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = async ({config, mode}) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets/styles/'),
    });

    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: 'vue-loader'
    });

    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
            { loader: 'vue-style-loader' },
            { loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
        ]
    });

    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
            { loader: 'vue-style-loader' },
            { loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
            { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
            { loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
                options: {
                    sourceMap: true,
                    resources: [
                        path.resolve('../src/assets/styles/_globals.scss')
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    });

    return config;
};
```

Comment: At a guess, Webpack doesn't know to _try_ and treat the request for `FaaH1` as `FaaH1.vue`. Try being specific in the `import` path, ie `import FaaH1 from "../src/components/texts/headings/FaaH1.vue"`

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, Webpack doesn't know to *try* and treat the request for `FaaH1` as `FaaH1.vue`. Try being specific in the `import` path, ie

```js
import FaaH1 from "../src/components/texts/headings/FaaH1.vue"
```

Alternatively, add `.vue` to the list of Webpack [`resolve.extensions`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveextensions)

```js
config.resolve.extensions.push('.vue')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if we could register the Vue global component in the following way.
the `Vue.component()` did take function type as its second argument. But I think the custom function might have insufficient properties in its prototype. So it's better to use `Vue.extend()` instead of arrow function here.

```
// Perhaps NG
export const faaH1 = () => ({
    components: {FaaH1},
    template: '<faa-h1>Heading H1</faa-h1>'
});

// This should work
export const faaH1 = Vue.extend({
    components: {FaaH1},
    template: '<faa-h1>Heading H1</faa-h1>'
})

Vue.component('faa-h1', FaaH1);
```